# VBA Word 07/13 Macro To Decrease Left Indent On All Tables By 0.45 Picas

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro that will enable me to reduce the Left Indent of all tables in a document by 0.45 picas. I am familiar with being able to write one that includes a specific amount, but I don't even know if it's possible to reduce or subtract an amount from a measurement within VBA Word.

Our company's tables had to be 0.45 picas indented in Word 2007 due to the uneven alignment of the left side of the box. In Word 2013, this indent is no longer necessary so all of our preexisting documents appear unnecessarily indented by 0.45 picas.

This is all I could come up with as an example:

```
Sub IndentAllTablesByAmount()

Dim oTbl As Word.Table
  For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    With oTbl.Range
    .Tables(1).Rows.LeftIndent = PicasToPoints(-0.45)

    End With

  Next oTbl
End Sub
```

But instead of putting a set number as a measurement, I want to minus that amount from the differently indented tables.

Comment: What have you done sofar? Show us the code please. What is Left Indent of a table? Does the table have to move to the left, does the paragraph(s) of the first column has to move or does the paragraph(s) of every cell have to move to the left?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. 

No code, yet. I don't even know how to begin to approach this problem. There are randomly indented tables in the document and all of them need to come back to the left by 0.45 picas. So, basically, I'm looking for a way to decrease all left table indents by 0.45 picas.

Comment: If you're able to do it in the UI (and it can be done, via the Table Properties) then record these steps in a macro in order to get the basic code as a starting point. You can then use the [edit] link below your question to copy the code into the question (and please remember to format it as code).

Comment: Please see the code in the edited original post.

Comment: @WillieD.Washington When you want to "flag" someone, so that they know you've answered, you need to precede their name with a @, as I've done for you. Otherwise, no one will know you've replied/edited.

Comment: @Cindy Meister - Oh, that's good to know. Thank you very much, Cindy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basic math, really...

```
Sub IndentAllTablesByAmount()

  Dim oTbl As Word.Table
  For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    oTbl.Rows.LeftIndent = oTbl.Rows.LeftIndent - PicasToPoints(0.45)
  Next oTbl
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I love it and it gets me closer to what I need. However, it's giving me this error: Run-time error '5149': The measurement must be between -1584pt and 1584pt.

Comment: That's odd... I did test it and I just tested it again: no error. Is this happening for all tables in the document? (When you get the error, you can drag the error-pointer down a line then press F5 to continue to the next table in the loop.) Or just a particular one?

Comment: I believe I pinpointed where the error was coming from. I had a table within a table, an unfortunate byproduct of our department with respect to specific boilerplate items that aren't common to all forms. I can just manually adjust those tables. Thank you again for your patience and assistance, Cindy! It is very appreciated.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks again. I was wondering what that was for. I thought it was another type of arrow. lol And for further clarification, it was a "table within a frame" that caused the error.